# Link mysql query result to url of same name

Tags: php, sql, html

My query finds the 'username' of users in the database, based on an age range. I want to make the 'username' in the results link to example.com/username or username.example.com or whatever is the simplest.

Here is my code:

```
$term = $_POST['term'];

$sql = mysql_query("select * from Users1 
WHERE `age` BETWEEN " . $_POST['age1'] . " and " . $_POST['age2'] . "

");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
echo 'Username: '.$row['username'];
}
```

Any help much appreciated!

Thanks a lot

Comment: You are using deprecated functions, and not sanitizing input. Please use `PDO`. (Also, you should already know how to echo out an anchor tag and some text)

Comment: Search Rewrite url with php on google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to make the 'username' in the results link to example.com/username or username.example.com or whatever is the simplest.

Then why don't you just echo that?

```
echo "<a href='http://example.com/".$row['username']."'>".$row['username']."</a>";
```